# Center floated Elements

Tags: jquery, css

I've explored this a rediculous amount, but I think I'm over thinking it! Basically:

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/EugZp/2/

I've got that ^ which works great, although I need the text to be center aligned with the text above it. I've tried using `display: inline-block` on the child elements and `text-align:center;` on their parents, which does center them, but then the jquery that animates them doesn't work properly because they're all aligned together not separate I believe.

Does anyone know of any tricks?

Comment: You need the slogan to be centered, right? Why not put them in a parent div and center that div by giving it a fixed width and margin: auto?

Comment: Hi @JeroenMoons, because I need each "div or Slogan" to be separate so that they can animate separately.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't prevent you from putting the separate divs in one container. fiddle on the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the updated fiddle i hope you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/EugZp/9/

Comment: The "technical artist" text doesn't pop-up in that fiddle

Comment: @SeanDunwoody in which browser you are lookin this fiddle?? because in firefox it works perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

You put them in a parent div and center that div, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EugZp/10/)

UPDATE: Fiddle fixed for Firefox and IE9, width increased.

Comment: Fixing a tight width on a text element is a bad practice. Not every browser will show the exact same font' size. This fiddle still doesn't work on my FF, but fixed IE 9 issue.